# Data Loader on MacOS - java.lang.NullPointerException with Zulu/OpenJDK 11

Tags: data-loader, java, mac-os-x

```
Last login: Thu Aug 27 14:29:01 on ttys000
/Users/vamshikrishna/dataloader/v49.0.0/dataloader.command ; exit;
vamshikrishna@MacBook-Pro-6 ~ % /Users/vamshikrishna/dataloader/v49.0.0/dataloader.command ; exit;

*************************************************************************
**            ___  ____ ___ ____   _    ____ ____ ___  ____ ____       **
**            |  \ |__|  |  |__|   |    |  | |__| |  \ |___ |__/       **
**            |__/ |  |  |  |  |   |___ |__| |  | |__/ |___ |  \       **
**                                                                     **
**  Data Loader v49 is a Salesforce supported Open Source project to   **
**  help you import data to and export data from your Salesforce org.  **
**  It requires Zulu OpenJDK 11 to run.                                **
**                                                                     **
**  Github Project Url:                                                **
**       https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader                     **
**  Salesforce Documentation:                                          **
**       https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm    **
**                                                                     **
*************************************************************************

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home
2020-08-27 14:38:24,519 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:468) - Reading log-conf.xml in /Users/vamshikrishna/dataloader/v49.0.0/configs/log-conf.xml
2020-08-27 14:38:24,571 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initLog (Controller.java:477) - The log has been initialized
2020-08-27 14:38:24,585 INFO  [main] controller.Controller createDir (Controller.java:306) - Config directory already exists: /Users/vamshikrishna/dataloader/v49.0.0/configs
2020-08-27 14:38:24,587 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initConfig (Controller.java:396) - Looking for file in config path: /Users/vamshikrishna/dataloader/v49.0.0/configs/config.properties
2020-08-27 14:38:24,588 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initConfig (Controller.java:429) - User config is found in /Users/vamshikrishna/dataloader/v49.0.0/configs/config.properties
2020-08-27 14:38:24,788 INFO  [main] controller.Controller initConfig (Controller.java:439) - The controller config has been initialized
2020-08-27 14:38:25,434 INFO  [main] config.LastRun load (LastRun.java:96) - Last run info will be saved in file: /Users/vamshikrishna/dataloader/v49.0.0/configs/ui_lastRun.properties
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.onPaint(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel$1.paintControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.onPaint(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel$1.paintControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.onPaint(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel$1.paintControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.onPaint(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel$1.paintControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.onPaint(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel$1.paintControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.onPaint(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel$1.paintControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.onPaint(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel$1.paintControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.onPaint(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel$1.paintControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.getTotalSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel.onPaint(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel$1.paintControl(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawWidget(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.drawRect(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationNextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.nextEventMatchingMask(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.ui.LoaderWindow.run(LoaderWindow.java:149)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.createAndShowGUI(Controller.java:266)
    at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:50)
```

Comment: Might be an issue with install. Try version 50. If you still get a NPE, open an issue on [github](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader)

Comment: There is an open issue created for the error you reported- https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues/215 according to which this happens from v45.0.0. Can you try with less than version 45 and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: (Fed, 25 2021)

V51 is out where all the issues have been fixed. Download it from your org.

### Edit: (DEC, 28 2020)

- [This issue has been fixed with the new version of the Dataloader. Take a look at the Github issue page for more information. The following link can be found on this page but I've put it here for more convenience.](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/issues/217)
- [use this link to download Dataloader V50.0 which contains the fix for the macOS Big Sur.](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/files/5599246/dataloader_mac.zip)

---

### My previous answer

This worked for me after spending so many hours trying to find a solution.
My macOS version: 10.15.7 Catalina

- Scroll down to the Zulu Java 11 (LTS) section [from here.](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?package=jdk)
  [image: Make sure you download this specific Zulu version]
- Use this command `open /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` to open the java virtual machines folder and remove all the Zulu versions from there (make sure none of these are required for other software to run, for me none were!)
- Now install the Zulu file you've downloaded.
- Download data loader from your org's UI as you'd do normally and install it

**Note: Make sure there's a single Zulu in your `JavaVirtualMachines` folder. Also, the version of Zulu in the screenshot is the only one that worked for me**

Check out this repo for older versions of Data Loader: https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases

***I hope this helps you. If it does, please upvote and select as the best answer.*** Cheers!!

Comment: My mac version is 11.0.1 (20B29) MacOS Big Sur.. it opens but all white screen even with Light Mode