# Salesforce Dataloader on Mac doesn't work past the select object page

Tags: data-loader, dataloader.io, dataloader-batch

I have attempted to use the Dataloader download for Mac several times to no avail. I am able to get to this screen (First Picture):
[image]

Once I hit next, I get a message stating: Initialization succeeded.

Then nothing happens. I don't get the option to hit finish.

If I hit next again, it gives me the same message: Initialization succeeded

Things I've tried: Re-downloading and re-installing Dataloader according to the Salesforce steps listed on the website. Re-authorizing use of unidentified software in Privacy & Security settings.

I would love some help to resolve this. I am unable to use the web version of Dataloader as it fails if I submit anything more than 30-40 records, and have about 13,000 records to update. I'd really like to not have to submit 325 separate spreadsheets with all the impending fails for different reasons (updating historical data on old opportunities).

Happy to resolve either the Mac software of dataloader or if someone has any ideas for web version IO. I need to get all these records updated by the end of this week.

Comment: I have same issue on BigSur. My advise is to download older version (v44) of dataloader -- that one works with all screens shown

Comment: [If you still have this issue check out my answer here. Use the link to download Dataloader V50.0 in which the problem has been solved.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/318084/data-loader-on-macos-java-lang-nullpointerexception-with-zulu-openjdk-11/327206#327206)  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved on latest update.

Reference: [Github Issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/pull/229)